# Why IF statement iterate over all AND conditions even if the first is false

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, jit

In c# i've an IF condition like this

```
if(x != null && x.myprop != "value")
{
//
}
```

when x is null why the compiler continues after '&&' operator even if the condition is guarantee to be not satsfied.

i've null exceptions if i do x.myprop when x is null, i know that '?' fix the problem but i can't understand why it continues.
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: not possible - _The conditional-AND operator (&&) performs a logical-AND of its bool operands, but only evaluates its second operand if necessary._ [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-and-operator)

Comment: Note that x.myprop may still be null when x is not.

Comment: Perhaps you did not use `&&` but rather just `&`

Comment: What's the type of `myprop`? Does this type overload the `!=` operator and throws if the left operand (`myprop`) is null? Either that or you used `&` instead of `&&`.

Comment: Are you sure this is where you are getting the null reference exception?

Comment: try rewriting as _"if(x != null) { if (x.myprop != "value") { // } }"_ - to check if you still get a null exception.

Comment: Are you asking about the compiler or about run time? because if it's the first, the compiler does not (and in fact, can not) evaluate the condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [&& operator in C# short circuits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-and-operator) so you cannot possibly be seeing this behaviour.

> The conditional-AND operator (&&) performs a logical-AND of its bool
>   operands, but only evaluates its second operand if necessary.

However, are you sure you have not mistakenly used the & operator ([which does not short circuit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/and-operator))?

> The binary & operator evaluates both operators regardless of the first
>   one's value, in contrast to the conditional AND operator &&.

Answer (score 1):

What you are explaining is impossible. The `null pointer` exception probably happens in another part of the code. In `C#` relying in short circuiting (this is what you are describing) is perfectly fine.

The specs say:

> The && and || operators are called the conditional logical operators.
>   They are also called the “shortcircuiting” logical operators. ... The
>   operation x && y corresponds to the operation x & y, except that y is
>   evaluated only if x is true ... The operation x && y is evaluated as
>   (bool)x ? (bool)y : false. In other words, x is first evaluated and
>   converted to type bool. Then, if x is true, y is evaluated and
>   converted to type bool, and this becomes the result of the operation.
>   Otherwise, the result of the operation is false.